# Error "TypeError: FirstForm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'"

Tags: python, django

Good day!

When working views.py constantly you get this kind of error:

TypeError: FirstForm() missing 1 required positional argument: 'request'

Views.py

```
def FirstForm(request):
if request.method == 'GET':
    form = FirstForm()
else:
    form = FirstForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        date = form.cleaned_data['date']
        number = form.cleaned_data['number']
        try:
            send_mail(email, (name, date, number), settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['daribian@list.ru'])
        except BadHeaderError:
            return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
        return redirect('success')
return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})

def successView(request):
    return HttpResponse('Success!')
```

Сan you tell me what the problem is?

Comment: Please update your question with the full error traceback.

Comment: You name the view exactly the same as the form, hence you call the view, not the form...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your view has the same name as the form, hence if you call `FirstForm`, you will call the view, not the form.

Therefore it is better to name the view, different, for example `first_view`:

```
def first_view(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':
        form = FirstForm()
    else:
        form = FirstForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        if form.is_valid():
            name = form.cleaned_data['name']
            email = form.cleaned_data['email']
            date = form.cleaned_data['date']
            number = form.cleaned_data['number']
            try:
                send_mail(email, (name, date, number), settings.EMAIL_HOST_USER, ['daribian@list.ru'])
            except BadHeaderError:
                return HttpResponse('Invalid header found.')
            return redirect('success')
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'form': form})
```

> **Note**: according to [**PEP-8**](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), you should write the functions in *snake_case*, not *camelCase*, so `success_view`, instead of <s>`successView`</s>.

Comment: Thanks! You've been very helpful!